# Http Header Authentication on post request AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, post, file-upload, afnetworking, basic-authentication

I am trying to create a `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` using AFNetworking's AFHttpClient. It must authenticate with a ASP.NET REST service using Http Authorization Header. Therefore I pass username and password to the Http Authorization Header using `setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password:`. In the body of the request I am passing a large file, several MBs. If the Header authentication fails, I want the request to get block and go in failure state before finishing the file send. There should be something that prevents the database send in case of authentication failure, but I cannot figure out what. In the current situation the AFHttpRequestOperation starts to send the file and notifies of the error only at the end of the file send.
This is the code:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://v-moxdevelop/MOX.UploadDBService/UploadDB/"]];

NSString *psw = @"psw";
NSString *userName = @"username";

[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:selectedLoginItem.user password:@"psw"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upload/%@/%@/%@", UDID, [selectedLoginItem.firm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""], [selectedLoginItem.user stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]]  parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:zipFilePath fileName:[zipFilePath lastPathComponent] mimeType:@"application/zip"];
}];

[request setTimeoutInterval:INT32_MAX];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];



operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];


__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *locOperation, id responseObject) {
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {

 }];



[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: It looks like you're making one HTTP request; the server won't respond denying authorization until your request is completed (ie, your file is uploaded).  Can you make one request checking the authorization, and then make this second request in the first request's success block?

Comment: If I cannot respond before file upload is finished (server-side), then the solution you pointed out is the only feasible one. In this case I should track inside the web service the user that has been authorized  with the first request and check it in the second request. Any suggestion how to that inside a WebInvoke ASP.NET web service?

Comment: No, you should ask that as a separate question designed to attract people who use WebInvoke, not people who use AFNetworking :-)